# Where do I find android gradle plugin for the latest canary build of Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

On the [guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#offline) for building Android projects offline, there is a link to the maven artifacts and gradle plugin for download. The instructions says they need to be unzipped and put in a directory called ~/.android/manual-offline-m2 and then create a script called offline.gradle the given code in ~/.gradle/init.d/offline.gradle.

This will probably be working fine for the latest stable version of Android studio, but since I am using Canary version 4.0.0-alpha07, I have no idea where to find android studio gradle plugin for this version of the IDE. The Android website obviously does not point to any download or archive to this version of the plugin. It only gives the download link for gradle plugin 3.5.0-beta01. Android Studio 4.0.0 Canary 7 does not accept this version of plugin although configure is successful when this version of plugin is applied in application build.gradle.

So, the question is how can I download (where) the gradle plugin for the latest Canary build of Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

you can download it from here https://nexus.xebialabs.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/. you need to recursively download the folder and files using wget.

for example

```
wget --continue --directory-prefix="location-to-save" --no-check-certificate --no-parent --recursive --timestamping "https://nexus.xebialabs.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/
```

you need to install wget first.